# Speech to Text using Twilio

Tags: twilio, speech-to-text, botframework

We use microsoft botframework for our chatbots. We would want to enable Voice channel to our bot. Is there a way to solution this? Does Twilio have anything that can add speech capabilities to our bot. Our bots are exposed via webchat components, skype, facebook messenger etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no way within Botframework to add voice capabilities from Twilio, however receiving calls works in a similar way. [When someone calls your Twilio number you receive a webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) which you can [respond to with TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/your_response) to tell Twilio what to do with the call.

To then perform things by voice action you can [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) the caller's response and set the [`transcribe` parameter to `true`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe). You also need to set a [`transcribeCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe-callback) as the transcription is done asynchronously. Once you receive that callback, the [text of the transcription will be available as a parameter in the request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe-callback). You could also perform the transcription yourself with a third party service by just taking the [recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action-parameters) and sending it off.

Once you receive the transcription you can then make your decision as the the next step of the conversation and [redirect the live call to the next step of your process using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state).

This is just a high level overview of how you might accomplish this. Let me know if it is of any help.

Comment: Philnash. looks like a plan. Is there a sample code somewhere for the solution you have described in para 2? I will add this as middleware and try it out.

Comment: There is a tutorial on recording and transcription in our tutorials section. If you're using botframework then I'm guessing you want either [Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/node/express) or [C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/csharp/mvc).

Answer (score 0):

Voximal offers as Twillo a similar product but based on VoiceXML. The difference is that Voximal integrates natively most of STT engines (Microsoft, Google, Watson, iSpeech) in the solution (you only need to set the key or the user/password to configure them). You use a builtin grammar "text" to translate. Then the processing is very similar to the Twilio. You need to push the content to a chatbot engine (HTTP/XML/JSON), and you have a way to play the result with a TTS engine.
Have a look  to the Parrot example (a script that repeats all you said using the STT and TTS) :

https://github.com/voximal/voicexml-examples/blob/master/parrot/parrot.vxml